# Memory leak after upgrading asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

We currently have an mvc3 webapp running live, earlier this week we tried upgrading to mvc4, but after we published the website w3wp.exe started eating lots of memory (> 2gb) and got timeouts on the application pool.

We use Unity (latest version) with unity.mvc3, we use a special lifetimemanager from unity.mvc3 to dispose the dbcontext.

We searched with ANTS memory profiler for issues but couldn't find any. Only the live site seems to get this problem.

Does anyone have some pointers here?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: We downgraded back to mvc 3 for now. But, with what I know now, I could tackle the problem I think, we'll go back to mvc4 next month. To tackle the problem I would now use windbg, take a memory dump when the memory is low (at the start), and another when the memory is high. Then compare values in windbg with dumpheap -stat. This way you can easily see what's causing it.

Comment: we are having the same problem. if I have just one action that returns a partial view, if I go into a browser, go to the url for the action, and just hold down f5 to load as fast as possible, the memory usage will periodically jump up 1mb or so, and never come back down. over time this will keep going up and up. when we expose our server to real load, this continues until gigs of memory are used, the CPU is steadily over 80%, and the site takes 30 seconds and more to respond to page requests.

Comment: Hi, see my previous comment on how to resolve this with windbg.